# Find a solution of $xe^{x/2}=C$

Tags: calculus

Sorry for my poor notation.
If $xe^{x/2}=C$

what is $x$ (interpreted by $C$)?

It means, $\ln(x) + \frac{x}{2}= \ln(C)$

Can I find the solution?

Comment: are you familiar with the LambertW function?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not familiar with the LambertW function.

Comment: Then $x/2\, e^{x/2} = C/2$, i.e. $x = 2\, W(C/2)$ where $W$ is the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). If you prefer, this kind of equation may be solved numerically, e.g. using Newton's method.

Comment: Thank you @Harry49 and Dr. Sonnhard Graubner